# Wrong header type rar android apk

Tags: java, android, rar

When I release a new apk and share it in rar format. 
When I install the folder in to my local file system, and try to open the rar file, I get the following error, Wrong header type rar android apk.

Any idea why this happens and how to solve it ?

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Did you compress it with WinRar? Are they the same version of RAR (compressed and decompressed with different versions)? Suggestion try zip instead!

Comment: Well the comprassing tool is WinRar on desktop , but the depcompress tool is ES file manager in the smart device. Do you think it may cause to the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get more reliable results, you should do one of the following:

- Share your APK without putting it into a RAR or a ZIP. As APK files are already compressed, you won't make it much smaller by compressing it. This is also easier for the end user, as they do not need to decompress it first. Some phones do not have an app installed for extracting ZIP or RAR files, and users will not want to install another app just to install yours.
- Put it into a ZIP. As I said, this probably won't make much of a difference to the file size, but it should be compatible with most devices. (Provided that the device has an app installed for extracting ZIP files)
- Or, when you are creating the RAR file, tell WinRAR to use the older RAR file format, RAR4, instead of RAR5. The problem is that ES file Explorer (which you are using) does not properly support the newer RAR files.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: APK files already compressed but when you have lots of images in your apk, comprassing it really works. 50 mb of apk can go down to 28 mb.

ZIP format worked btw.  RAR did not work somehow, even though its file format was not RAR5.  

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the .rar file with WinRAR, make sure that the `RAR5` archive format isn't chosen. WinRAR 5.x can create RAR files in the older format just fine. This is even the default option in WinRAR.

Another idea is that compression is not supported? (just packing of the files)
Does the Android APK support RAR files at all?

Comment: Yes you are able to RAR an APK file and distribution in that way is possible. When you have a hybrid mobile app for instance,  you may end up with huge package size because of the high quality images.  Almost 50% compression is possible over apks (in this  specific case) .